# Including additional alias files in Sendmail

Tags: sendmail, alias

I've run into an issue with a piece of third party software that creates it's own alias file to be used by sendmail. Looking through the configuration options, google, and the man pages it seems like I can only define one alias file which means either I only get all the software's addresses or all of the local aliases.

I have tried appending my own entries to the software's alias file but it gets rebuilt everytime there is a change of addresses and my entries get blown away.

My question is, is there a way to define addional alias files in sendmail.mc or to include additional addresses from another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [Sendmail documentation](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/ostype.html#ALIAS_FILE), you'll find:

```
ALIAS_FILE  [/etc/mail/aliases] The location of the text version of the
alias file(s). It can be a comma-separated list of names (but be sure you
quote values with commas in them -- for example, use define(`ALIAS_FILE',
`a,b') to get "a" and "b" both listed as alias files; otherwise the
define() primitive only sees "a").
```

So, you can edit your sendmail.mc file to use a common-delimited list of alias files, and then regenerate your sendmail.cf.  And restart Sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a second aliases file, but you can include a file using the syntax

    `:include: /path/name` 

So define all your aliases in your aliases file, and then include the one created by your software.

Comment: I tried add the following line exactly to my /etc/aliases file: ":include:       /etc/mail/list_aliases" and ran newaliases. It gave me the following error: "/etc/aliases: line 99: :include:        /etc/mail/list_aliases... illegal alias name"

Comment: After looking up the syntax it seems that the :include: statement is a destination for an alias but can not define aliases themselves

Answer (score 0):

Aliases of the form

```
alias     :include:/path/to/some/alias_file
```

take their email targets from the contents of alias_file.  Put each email address on a separate line.

For instance, if /usr/local/etc/my_list contains a list of addresses that you want to alias as "myfriends", you would use this entry in /etc/aliases:

```
myfriends     :include:/usr/local/etc/my_list
```

with my_list containing legal email addresses one per line like this

```
phyllis
joe@example.com
sara@example.com
```